# Add print button in the "Review order" page

Tags: commerce

I want to know, is there any way to add print button to "Review order" page.

by clicking this button, a pop up page is loaded with good style for print mode and user can print the cart items , taxes and all information in Review order page.

Please guide me.

Comment: do you achieve your job with `printfriendly` ? I have another solution without need install this heavy module

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [PrintFriendly & PDF](https://drupal.org/project/printfriendly) module, which has a version for Drupal 7 and one for Drupal 8. (The development snapshot for Drupal 8 has been created on July 27, 2017.)

The description of the module says:

> The #1 Print and PDF button for your Drupal site. Printer Friendly
>   pages without coding, css, or print.css. Fast, easy, and professional.
>
> The Print Friendly & PDF button saves paper and ink when printing or
>   creating a PDF. It's fast, easy, and looks great when printed. Add the
>   button now, and your users will see the difference.

Using this module you can add a print button to review order pages.

Answer (score 0):

The issue of PrintFriendly & PDF does not work with views in case you need, you can try with https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print if is view page.